# Filter a List View based on data in another list

Tags: 2013, list, list-view, filter, task-list

I'm looking for guidance on how to approach a problem.

I have two lists, **Goals** and **Tasks**. Goals is a simple custom list with Name and People-Involved. Tasks is a task list with a lookup field to Goals>Name.

All Tasks belong to a certain Goal. Goals have People-Involved. I want a list view that shows only the Tasks that belong to Goals that the current user is involved in.

Explained another way:
SHOW tasks WHERE tasks>goals>people-involved INCLUDES [me]

Should I be looking at a JavaScript solution? Use JSON/REST to query the other list and then use the results of the query to filter the task list view? How would I go about implementing this?

Environment: Office 365 / SharePoint Online

Answer (score 0):

Go to 'Tasks' **List Settings** > '**Name**' Lookup column

Under **Additional column settings**, you might have '***Add a column to show each of these additional fields***' , there choose the '**Person Involved**' and Save.

Now modify the view, under Filter > Choose '**Name:Person Involved**' column and the save the filter as it is equal to [Me]

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I should have included in my post that I have already tried that method. Unfortunately you cannot add _additional fields_ if those fields are also lookup fields. The People-Involved is the People and Groups data type, a lookup field.

Answer (score 0):

We could use a **workflow** to get the specific '**People-Involved**' value from the '**Goals**' list, then store this data to a people picker column in the '**Tasks**' list.

After that, we could filter the tasks in '**Tasks**' list view based on **[Me]** (current user).

1. Create a hidden people picker column in '**Tasks**' list.
2. Create a workflow for '**Tasks**' list in SharePoint Designer, and make it start when a task is created or edited.
3. In this workflow, use '**Update List Item**' action to set the people picker column (created in step 1) to the '**People-Involved**' value of the lookup item.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add both the lists in separate web parts on a page and connect Goals list web part to Tasks. The Tasks list web part will be filtered based on what Goal is selected. You can also display Tasks filtered for logged in user using [Me].